# How does a pyrrole react with its C2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds

First of all, thank you for reading my question. There is a mechanism I read where the pyrrole reacts with its C2 but I can't draw the arrows so I don't know if I am correct to think that :

[image]

the ester: is a deactivating group because it has a Mesomeric electron-withdrawing effect (M-) so it deactivates the C4
the methoxy: is an activating group because of its electron-donating effect (M+) so it activates the C4

--> and M+>M- so it will react on C4

But the pyrrole likes to react on its C2 but it is deactivated by the ester (because in para)

Please explain me how does it work I am very lost...

Comment: All of your mesomeric effects may serve to slow the rate of the reaction but reaction occurs as shown.

Comment: Actually I think I understood why I was lost, because I was thinking of the reaction like it is SEar but here it's in SNar, right ?

Comment: It sounds to me that you are memorizing too much and not going with the facts. You're given the answer. Now "push mechanistic arrows" accordingly.